# Как на всем сайте wordpress заменить цены RUB на РУБ (установлен плагин easydigitaldownloads)?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин

Есть сайт на `wordpress` с установленным [плагином для скачки цифровых товаров](https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/)

Товары в рублях. Хочу заменить все вхождения **RUB** на **РУБ**
[Нашел фильтр](http://hookr.io/filters/edd_format_amount/)

Делаю так, но возвращается только неотформатированная цена с прежним символом

```
// define the edd_format_amount callback 
function filter_edd_format_amount( $formatted, $amount, $decimals, $decimal_sep, $thousands_sep ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    $newamount = str_replace("RUB", "РУБ", $amount);
    return $newamount; 
};
```

Что нужно исправить, чтобы произошла замена и не повлияет ли это при передаче информации в платежную систему (правильно ли распознает код страны оплаты)?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция не может быть вызвана сама по себе, она никак не привязана к фильтру `edd_format_amount`. Вам нужно зарегистрировать свой фильтр в WordPress с помощью `add_filter()`.

```
// define the edd_format_amount callback
function filter_edd_format_amount( $formatted, $amount, $decimals, $decimal_sep, $thousands_sep ) {
    // make filter magic happen here...
    $formatted = str_replace( 'RUB', 'РУБ', $formatted );

    return $formatted;
}

add_filter( 'edd_format_amount', 'filter_edd_format_amount', 10, 5 );
```

Обратите внимание на то, что фильтр всегда фильтрует первый аргумент (`$formatted`), и возвращать надо его модификацию. Остальные аргументы носят вспомогательных характер.

На вопрос о том, повлияет ли это на работу системы оплаты, ответить невозможно - нет информации о том, как используется строка `$formatted`. Но из общих соображений могу сказать, что вряд ли она передаётся в систему оплаты, куда отправляют обычно неформатированные, структурированные данные.

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ, но оказывается это не тот фильтр, он фильтрует только числовое значение, а не символ валюты
Может быть разгадка - здесь, но тут используется функция добавления
https://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/272-adding-currency-support-eddcurrencies

Answer (score 0):

Нашел отличную [статью](https://www.sellwithwp.com/pricing-remove-currency-symbol/), где собраны все фильтры изменения/удаления символов для различных плагинов. И на [гитхабе](https://gist.github.com/bekarice/17238f1fe1651aa17410)
В моем случае сработал вот такой фильтр:

```
// Changes currency symbol from the shop price display
function sww_change_edd_rub_currency_symbol( $output, $currency, $price ) {
    $output = $price. ' РУБ';
    return $output;
}
// This will apply to USD, but the usd in this filter can be replaced with your currency symbol
add_filter( 'edd_rub_currency_filter_after', 'sww_change_edd_rub_currency_symbol', 10, 3 );
```